# prometheus-nginxlog-exporter dosn't show correct statistics

Tags: nginx, prometheus

i've just started to work with prometheus-nginxlog-exporter
https://github.com/martin-helmich/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter

my nginx.conf has only one change

```
log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_method "$request_uri " $status';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  custom;
```

I have two simple site

```
server {
    listen       82;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access_default_site.log  custom;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

upstream prom {
    server 127.0.0.1:9090;
    keepalive 15;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      auth_basic "Restricted Access";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.prom;

      proxy_pass http://prom;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
      proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
    }
}
```

etc/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter.hcl

```
listen {
  port = 4040
}

namespace "nginx" {
  source = {
    files = [
      "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    ]
  }
  metrics_override = { prefix = "allnginx" }
  namespace_label = "vhost"
  format = "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_method \"$request_uri\" $status"


  labels {
    app = "prod"
  }
}

namespace "default" {
  source = {
    files = [
      "/var/log/nginx/access_default_site.log"
    ]
  }
  metrics_override = { prefix = "allnginx" }
  namespace_label = "vhost"
  format = "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_method \"$request_uri\" $status"


  labels {
    app = "test"
  }
}
```

if check prometheus metrics
`curl  http://localhost:4040/metrics`

output is

```
# HELP allnginx_http_response_count_total Amount of processed HTTP requests
# TYPE allnginx_http_response_count_total counter
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod",method="",status="200",vhost="nginx"} 28
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod",method="",status="302",vhost="nginx"} 7
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod",method="",status="400",vhost="nginx"} 30
# HELP allnginx_parse_errors_total Total number of log file lines that could not be parsed
# TYPE allnginx_parse_errors_total counter
allnginx_parse_errors_total{vhost="default"} 0
allnginx_parse_errors_total{vhost="nginx"} 0
```

`allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod",method="",status="200",vhost="nginx"} 28`
Why is method empty? How to configure it correct?

How to get statistics about requests to location e.g. how many requests to "/", "/api"

Answer (score 0):

as mentions in documentations
https://github.com/martin-helmich/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter#custom-labels-pass-through
we should you relabel

my working config is

```
listen {
  port = 4040
}

namespace "nginx" {
  source = {
    files = [
      "/var/log/nginx/access.log"
    ]
  }
  metrics_override = { prefix = "allnginx" }
  namespace_label = "vhost"
  format = "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_method \"$request_uri\" $status"
  relabel "method" { from = "request_method" }
  relabel "request_uri" { from = "request_uri" }
  labels {
    app = "prod"
  }
}

namespace "default" {
  source = {
    files = [
      "/var/log/nginx/access_default_site.log"
    ]
  }
  metrics_override = { prefix = "allnginx" }
  namespace_label = "vhost"
  format = "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_method \"$request_uri\" $status"
  relabel "method" { from = "request_method" }
  relabel "request_uri" { from = "request_uri" }

  labels {
    app = "test"
  }
}
```

in metrics we can see somthing like this

```
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod", instance="localhost:4040", job="nginx", method="DELETE", request_uri="/api/dashboards/uid/GLEY_3g7k", status="200", vhost="nginx"}
    1
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod", instance="localhost:4040", job="nginx", method="GET", request_uri="/", status="302", vhost="nginx"}
    1
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod", instance="localhost:4040", job="nginx", method="GET", request_uri="/", status="401", vhost="nginx"}
    2
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod", instance="localhost:4040", job="nginx", method="GET", request_uri="/api/alerts/states-for-dashboard?dashboardId=2", status="200", vhost="nginx"}
    1
allnginx_http_response_count_total{app="prod", instance="localhost:4040", job="nginx", method="GET", request_uri="/api/alerts/states-for-dashboard?dashboardId=3", status="200", vhost="nginx"}
```